# How can I sum TIME + DATETIME columns in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime, time

I have 2 columns ( 1 TIME, 1 DATETIME ) with this formats:

TIME: 24:00:00

DATETIME: 2014-07-29 00:00:00

How can I sum this 24 hours into the datetime column and put the result in a third column?

Thank you!!!!

Comment: What would the result be?

Comment: in this case.. one more day! 2014-07-30 00:00:00

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with the [ADDTIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime) function

```
SELECT ADDTIME(your_datetime, your_time) as your_sum
```

> ADDTIME() adds expr2 to expr1 and returns the result. expr1 is a time
>   or datetime expression, and expr2 is a time expression.
>
> mysql> SELECT ADDTIME('2007-12-31 23:59:59.999999', '1 1:1:1.000002');
>           -> '2008-01-02 01:01:01.000001'

Answer (score 1):

Use TIMESTAMP() MySQL function

Try

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP('2014-07-29 00:00:00','24:00:00');
```

it gives

```
2014-07-30 00:00:00
```

I hope this works for you